# Python compare partial string in a list with each other

Tags: python, regex, string, compare

I am trying to write a code to compare each string in a list to each other and then generate its regex for similarity

```
list = ["LONDON-UK-L16-N1",
        "LONDON-UK-L17-N1",
        "LONDON-UK-L16-N2",
        "LONDON-UK-L17-N2",
        "PARIS-France-L16-N2"]
```

I am trying to get an output as below

```
LONDON-UK-L(16|17)-N(1|2)
```

is that possible? thanks

Update: just to make it clear i am trying to
input: list, or strings
Action: compare list items to each other, and check for similarity (to fix it-first group of a string), and use regex for any other not similar part of item, so instead of having for items, we can have a single output (using regex)
output: regex to match not similar

input:
tez15-3-s1-y2
tez15-3-s2-y2
bro40-55-s1-y2

output:
tez15-3-s(1|2)-y2
,bro40-55-s1-y2

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you put up the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Wow, this is kind of reverse-`regex` problem.

Comment: the "PARIS-France-L16-N2" - part would make it hard to get to the exact output you are trying to get

Comment: Is it intentional that you have two copies of `"LONDON-UK-L16-N2"` in the list, and that the resulting regex matches `"LONDON-UK-L17-N2"` even though that's not in the list? Looks like a probable typo.

Comment: Also, do you specifically need the regex written that way, or would e.g. `LONDON-UK-L16-N1|LONDON-UK-L17-N1|LONDON-UK-L16-N2|LONDON-UK-L17-N2` be OK? It matches exactly the same strings, the only difference is the lack of capturing groups.

Comment: thanks but by this way, all the list item will be in same command, we need to separate by cities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this new (second) implementation on this problem, I think more accurate and hope helpful:

```
import re 

data = [
  'LONDON-UK-L16-N1',
  'LONDON-UK-L17-N1',
  'LONDON-UK-L16-N2',
  'LONDON-UK-L17-N2',
  'LONDON-UK-L18-N2',
  'PARIS-France-L16-N2',
]

def merge(data):
  data.sort()
  data = [y for y in [x.split('-') for x in data]]

  for col in range(len(data[0]) - 1, -1, -1):
    result = []

    def add_result():
      result.append([])
      if headstr:
        result[-1] += headstr.split('-')
      if len(list(findnum)) > 1:
        result[-1] += [f'{findstr}({"|".join(sorted(findnum))})']
      elif len(list(findnum)) == 1:
        result[-1] += [f'{findstr}{findnum[0]}']
      if tailstr:
        result[-1] += tailstr.split('-')

    _headstr = lambda x, y: '-'.join(x[:y])
    _tailstr = lambda x, y: '-'.join(x[y + 1:])
    _findstr = lambda x: re.findall('(\D+)', x)[0] if re.findall('(\D+)', x) else ''
    _findnum = lambda x: re.findall('(\d+)', x)[0] if re.findall('(\d+)', x) else ''

    headstr = _headstr(data[0], col)
    tailstr = _tailstr(data[0], col)
    findstr = _findstr(data[0][col])
    findnum = []

    for row in data:
      if headstr + findstr + tailstr != _headstr(row, col) + _findstr(row[col]) + _tailstr(row, col):
        add_result()
        headstr = _headstr(row, col)
        tailstr = _tailstr(row, col)
        findstr = _findstr(row[col])
        findnum = []
      if _findnum(row[col]) not in findnum:
        findnum.append(_findnum(row[col]))

    else:
        add_result()

    data = result[:]

  return ['-'.join(x) for x in result]

print(merge(data))  # ['LONDON-UK-L(16|17)-N(1|2)', 'LONDON-UK-L18-N2', 'PARIS-France-L16-N2']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, can you please advice which part in the code i can use it to fix a specific match, example: LONDON-UK-L18-S2-N1, LONDON-UK-L18-S1-N1
in that case the result will be LONDON-UK-L18-S(1|2)-N1, which is different location, so the result should be not match, we should get regex if all other fields are same, except L and N, thanks again for your utmost support

Comment: I just tried it again, 
data = [
  'LONDON-UK-L16-S1-N1',
  'LONDON-UK-L16-S2-N1',
]

output:['LONDON-UK-L16-S(1|2)-N1']

they aren't same location, we should match only L/N, can you direct me to which part in the code can be updated, as it is a bit advanced to my skills

Comment: I've tried to refactor the code but with no result, it's not a matter of a simple correction. I'm sorry but perhaps the problem needs a whole new approach and it's difficult to have the time.

Answer (score 3):

Its not entirely clear from your question what the exact problem is. Since the data you gave as an example is consistent and well ordered, this problem can be solved easily by simply splitting up the items in the list and categorising them.

```
loc_list = ["LONDON-UK-L16-N1", "LONDON-UK-L17-N1", "LONDON-UK-L16-N2", 
            "LONDON-UK-L16-N2", "PARIS-France-L16-N2"]

split_loc_list = [location.split("-")  for location in loc_list]

locs = {}

for loc in split_loc_list:
    locs.setdefault("-".join(loc[0:2]), {}).\
                        setdefault("L", set()).add(loc[2].strip("L"))

    locs.setdefault("-".join(loc[0:2]), {}).\
                        setdefault("N", set()).add(loc[3].strip("N"))

for loc, vals in locs.items():
    L_vals_sorted = sorted(list(map(int,vals["L"])))
    L_vals_joined = "|".join(map(str,L_vals_sorted))

    N_vals_sorted = sorted(list(map(int,vals["N"])))
    N_vals_joined = "|".join(map(str,N_vals_sorted))

    print(f"{loc}-L({L_vals_joined})-N({N_vals_joined})")
```

will output:

```
LONDON-UK-L(16|17)-N(1|2)
PARIS-France-L(16)-N(2)
```

Since there were only two tags here ("L" and "N"), I just wrote them into the code. If there are many tags possible, then you can strip by any letter using:

```
import re
split = re.findall('\d+|\D+', loc[2])
key, val = split[0], split[1]
locs.setdefault("-".join(loc[0:2]), {}).\
                        setdefault(key, set()).add(val)
```

Then iterate through all the tags instead of just fetching "L" and "N" in the second loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i think it is not accurate as the output includes N16|17 which we don't have in the input

Comment: Ah yes I included a typo, L_vals_sorted should read N_vals_sorted in the second to last line.. I'll fix the mistake

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented the following solution:

```
import re 

data = [
  'LONDON-UK-L16-N1',
  'LONDON-UK-L17-N1',
  'LONDON-UK-L16-N2',
  'LONDON-UK-L16-N2',
  'PARIS-France-L16-N2'
]

def deconstruct(data):
  data = [y for y in [x.split('-') for x in data]]
  result = dict()

  for x in data:
    pointer = result

    for y in x:
      substr = re.findall('(\D+)', y)
      if substr:
        substr = substr[0]
        if not substr in pointer:
          pointer[substr] = {0: set()}
        pointer = pointer[substr]

      substr = re.findall('(\d+)', y)
      if substr:
        substr = substr[0]
        pointer[0].add(substr)

  return result

def construct(data, level=0):
  result = []

  for key in data.keys():
    if key != 0:
      if len(data[key][0]) == 1:
        nums = list(data[key][0])[0]
      elif len(data[key][0]) > 1:
        nums = '(' + '|'.join(sorted(list(data[key][0]))) + ')'
      else:
        nums = ''

      deeper_result = construct(data[key], level + 1)
      if not deeper_result:
        result.append([key + nums])
      else:
        for d in deeper_result:
          result.append([key + nums] + d)

  return result if level > 0 else ['-'.join(x) for x in result]

print(construct(deconstruct(data)))
# ['LONDON-UK-L(16|17)-N(1|2)', 'PARIS-France-L16-N2']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried your solution but it gave inaccurate regex,
if input
data = [
  'LONDON-UK-L16-N1',
  'LONDON-UK-L17-N1',
  'LONDON-UK-L16-N2',
  'LONDON-UK-L18-N2',
  'PARIS-France-L16-N2'
]
output based on your solution will be as below as we don't have L18-N1 nor L17-N2
['LONDON-UK-L(16|17|18)-N(1|2)', 'PARIS-France-L16-N2']

Comment: I've posted a new (second) implementation on this problem, I think is more accurate and hope be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 'list' as a variable name... it's a reserved word.

```
import re

lst = ['LONDON-UK-L16-N1', 'LONDON-UK-L17-N1', 'LONDON-UK-L16-N2', 'LONDON-UK-L16-N2', 'PARIS-France-L16-N2']

def check_it(string):
    return re.search(r'[a-zA-Z\-]*L(\d)*-N(\d)*', string)

[check_it(x).group(0) for x in lst]
```

will output:

```
['LONDON-UK-L16-N1',
 'LONDON-UK-L17-N1',
 'LONDON-UK-L16-N2',
 'LONDON-UK-L16-N2',
 'PARIS-France-L16-N2']
```

From there, look into groups and define a group to cover the pieces that you want to use for similarity.

Comment: The OP is interested in **generating** the regex based on a list of strings, not in writing the regex to match all those strings in the list.

Comment: thanks for all of you for your help, but as Enrico's comment, i am trying to get regex not match--> i mean reverse regex